# Getting data from a servlet to JSP and sending that data again to another servlet through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and servlet. I am designing a library management system in tomcat version 10.0, in that when user sign-in using his userid and password in html form it will send it to login servlet once credentials matched using RequestDispatcher it sent userid to userlogin(home) JSP for further use.

Until this everything is working and in that JSP there is two actions, one is the user can check for book availability in MySQL Database and his/her book's return date, if he/she borrowed any book otherwise no books borrowed message will shown.

The task is, I want to get the above two actions' result through ajax. Once the user enters the book name to be searched in input field and button is pressed the ajax should call the servlet and get the value corresponding to it from database and create data in htmltable format and return it to ajax call and ajax on getting it, should display it in a particular div using innerhtml or DOM html function. The same method is user for getting the returndate of the book user borrowed.

Problem:

But once the book name entered in field and button is pressed the action is called but it shows a 405 error that the servlet doesnot allow GET method, eventhough in ajax call and my servlet I used POST method. I noticed a thing that when user sign-in, the URL bar shows login servlet URL eventhough the page shows JSP page and also once the ajax is called the data is send from login servlet(http://localhost:8080/library/UserLogin) and also received in the same login servlet(http://localhost:8080/library/UserLogin?search=java) which seems to working in get method (but I used POST on both sides though), so I guess the data is still moving in the same servlet URL.

**UserLogin.java**

```
 public class UserLogin extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    
    //getting userid and password for checking with database//
    String userid=request.getParameter("uid"); 
    String pass=request.getParameter("pwd");
    try{
        
        Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","password");
        PreparedStatement ps =connect.prepareStatement("select * from library.user where userid = ? and pass = ?");
        ps.setString(1, userid);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
        if(rs.next()){
            request.setAttribute("userid",userid);
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("userlogin.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
        else{
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:4200/user");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}}
```

'

**userlogin.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.jpg" type ="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Online Library</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-7x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by book genre (Eg:Search Java for Java books)" />
                <button id="getbook"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        <!--the button for ajax to get book availability table-->
            
        </form>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <button id="mybook">My Books and Due date</button>
  <!--the button for ajax to get user's book returndate table-->
  
    <%String suserid=(String)request.getAttribute("userid");
    out.println("name:"+suserid);%> <!--storing userid for using it for user's book returndate-->
    
  <div id="books"> <!--div tag where the table will show-->
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#getbook").click(function(){
                var search=$("#search").val()
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'Issuedbooks',
                    data:search,
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#books").html(response);              
                        },error:function(request,status,error){
                            alert("Error:"+error+status);
                        }
                });
            });
        $("#mybook").click(function(){
                var userid= suserid; /*I also doubt on this declaration if it is wrong give suggestion please*/
              $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'mybooks',
                    data:userid,
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                         $("#books").html(response);              
                        },error:function(request,status,error){
                           alert("Error:"+error+status);
                         }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Issuedbooks.java**

```
public class Issuedbooks extends HttpServlet {  
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
  throws ServletException, IOException { 

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><body>");   //creating a html table//
    String genre=request.getParameter("search");   //the value in input field of jsp page//

    try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","password");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from library.issue where genre='"+genre+"'");
            out.println("<table border=1>");
            out.println("<tr><th>Bookid</th><th>Returndate</th><th>Bookname</th><th>Authorname</th></tr>");    //creating table header//
            
            while(rs.next()){
                String bookid=rs.getString(3);
                String returndate=rs.getString(5);
                out.println("<tr><td>"+bookid+"</td><td>"+returndate+"</td>");
            }
            Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","password"); //as I have to get data from two database I have created two connections//
            Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery("select * from library.books where genre='"+genre+"'");
            while(rs1.next()){
                String bookname=rs1.getString(2);
                String authorname=rs1.getString(3);
                out.println("<td>"+bookname+"</td><td>"+authorname+"</td></tr>");  //continuing to add this in same table//
            }
            out.println("</table");
            out.println("</body></html>");   //end of htmltable//
        }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**mybooks.java**

```
public class mybooks extends HttpServlet {  
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException { 
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><body>");
    String userid=request.getParameter("suserid");  //getting userid from jsp which is obtained from userlogin servlet//

    try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","password");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from library.issue where userid='"+userid+"'");
            out.println("<table border=1>");
            out.println("<tr><th>Bookid</th><th>IssueId</th><th>Userid</th><th>Bookid</th><th>Issuedate</th><th>Returndate</th><th>Genre</th></tr>");
            
            if(rs.next()){
                String issueid=rs.getString(1);
                String userid=rs.getString(2);
                String bookid=rs.getString(3);
                String issuedate=rs.getString(4);
                String returndate=rs.getString(5);
                String genre=rs.getString(7);
                out.println("<tr><td>"+issueid+"</td><td>"+userid+"</td><td>"+bookid+"</td><td>"+issuedate+"</td><td>"+returndate+"</td><td>"+genre+"</td></tr>");
            }else{
                out.println("No books issued");
            }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

So these are my code and on running these I get error like this.
[HTTP GET is not supported by this url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxMQI.png) in my tomcat server. I did everything using POST method since I am getting error for using GET method and the url in jsp page still displays the userlogin servlet URL and the data isn't get passed this URL on calling ajax. I have checked with web.xml everything is fine.

Sorry for lengthy description, I just want to clearly describe my problem to get answers. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, your form is getting submit not ajax  . Simple fix will be adding `type="button"` to your button .

Comment: @Swati Thanks mam, It worked ajax is fetching table but table isn't showing any value other than table header. Is the method of creating a html table in servlet is good or should I use any other method to get table values. Need suggestion...!

Comment: Hi , did you check if `request.getParameter("search");` has any value ? Also , try changing this `data:search`  to `data:{"search" : search },`

Comment: @Swati Its working fine mam, and I am getting table but the second action isn't working. I received userid from loginservlet and converted to string and set its value to a input field so I can use it for ajax function. Userid is passing to servlet but the response is only just the table headers and there is no table data.

Comment: Hi, print and see if `userid` has any value . Also , no need to convert them in string because they are already string value and at your server `userid` column is Pk ? If yes just  convert that pass value to integer type .

Comment: @Swati My userid look like this mam 'userid=user1'. I am receiving it from login servlet. In the input field it appears and it is passing through ajax as 'form data (user_id:user1)'. In my database userid is 'VARCHAR' type not it is not 'Primary key' (Pk). So I guess it should be passed as String type right?

Comment: Yes . So, its not going inside while loop .. maybe check if query is correct or not . Try , that in some other page without ajax see if its fetching result or not .

Comment: @Swati Mam, Instead sending the default value in input field, I manually entered userid in the input field and passed it through ajax and using form submission method as you have said and I am receiving the expected output as table but I think once user signed in to home he/she doesn't like to enter his/her id again to get information specific to him/her right?. Is there any ways to avoid manually entering or re-entering the userid after signing in to get data specific to the user.

Comment: You can store userid in Httpsession and then use it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for sharing the code again but I didn't figure out where I am missing the part. Here I have only shared the part that isn't working

**userlogin.jsp**

```
   <%String userid=(String)request.getAttribute("userid");%>   //converted to received object to string here//                                                                                                    
 <input type="hidden" id="userid" value='<%out.println(userid);%>'> //set value of input as userid and hide it so I can use it for ajax//
<input type="button" id="mybook" value="My books and due date" />
<div id="books">
</div>
 <script>                                                                                                                                                                              
  $("#mybook").click(function(){
        console.log("test print");
        var userid= $("#userid").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'mybooks',
            data:{user_id:userid.toString()},   //I have a doubt whether it is changed to string or not so again tried to transfer it as string//
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#books").html(response);
            },error:function(request,status,error){
                alert("Error:"+error+status);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**mybooks.java**

```
public class mybooks extends HttpServlet {  
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
   throws ServletException, IOException { 
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><body>");
    String userid=request.getParameter("user_id");
    try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","password");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from library.issue where userid='"+userid+"'");
            out.println("<table border=1>");
            out.println("<tr><th>Bookid</th><th>IssueId</th><th>Userid</th><th>Bookid</th><th>Issuedate</th><th>Returndate</th><th>Genre</th></tr>"); //i am getting upto this content in response//
            while(rs.next()){
                String issueid=rs.getString(1);
                String uid=rs.getString(2);
                String bookid=rs.getString(3);
                String issuedate=rs.getString(4);
                String returndate=rs.getString(5);
                String genre=rs.getString(7);
                out.println( "<tr><td>"+issueid+"</td><td>"+uid+"</td><td>"+bookid+"</td><td>"+issuedate+"</td><td>"+returndate+"</td><td>"+genre+"</td></tr>"); //I didn't get this part in response, I doubt whether the data is receiving in servlet evethough it is passed here//
            }out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```